# Selective Rendering of PDF

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, rendering, postscript

I'd like to do something that I think many people would like to do, but the tools don't seem to exist.

The short form of my question is whether there is a library (C++ or Java) to parse a PDF produced by LaTeX and render it "in pieces," say a paragraph at a time, so that the rendering program can intersperse the rendered PDF with interactive widgets. Display PostScript would have been the way to do this, but that died years ago.

The goal is to use LaTeX to produce the text-based aspects of a presentation, while allowing the use of interactive tools. For example, suppose you want to explain how a lever works. LaTeX can be used for the static aspects of the discussion, including some static figures. But the user should also be able to interactively play with the inputs that affect how a lever works -- moving the fulcrum around or changing the weights on each end, say. The reader could print the document to read off-line normally, but they could also interact with it when on-line.

The path of least resistance is to use browser-based tools, but HTML/JS is pretty poor when it comes to anything more than a few simple formulas. Another solution is to insert hyperlinks in the PDF that lead to HTML pages, and that would work, but it's a Rube Goldberg approach, and it wouldn't be a smooth experience for the reader.

Comment: After some thought, one way to make this happen is to break the pdf produced by latex into multiple files, one file for each static portion. This can be done by varying the page sizes, then breaking the single pdf produced by latex on the page breaks. There will be some additional external housekeeping to keep these files straight, and so that the figure shown in the rendering program matches the figure shown in the version to be printed to paper.

Answer (score 1):

[Asymptote](https://ctan.org/pkg/asymptote) is a C-like language that can be included directly into your LaTeX documents. If you can persuade all your end users to only use Adobe Acrobat to display their PDFs, then Asymptote can embed interactive diagrams directly inside your PDF. Here's a [TUGboat article demonstrating a few interactive diagrams](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/%7Ebowman/publications/tb98bowman.pdf). All the content can be printed off just like any other PDF.

My personal experience with Asymptote is very limited, and I've never worked with the interactive portions of Asymptote. Although it seems to meet all the requirements stated in your question, I wouldn't recommend it unless you can *really* really ensure all your end user are using Adobe Acrobat. HTML can still do a good job of displaying math with MathJax, and JavaScript + SVG can work wonders for creating interactive diagrams.